# Notification APP server migration from GCM to FCM

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an old notification server Java SE 6 and using gcm-server.jar to send notification. In order to migrate to fcm, do I need to do some coding to send a HTTP post?

Comment: Have you checked out the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update-server-endpoints)?

Comment: Yes i do. ...Update your server code to use new FCM endpoints....My manager also read that and request me to follow the recommendation. But i have no idea how to make it done without revised gcm jar or coding.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find the right jar-file?  Did you have issues with the new library?